# React Navigation, How do I test a the path of a Navlink?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, navigation, react-navigation, enzyme

I'm trying to write a test to check the path of a navlink, but it keeps failing with the error 'wrapper.find... is not a function:

here is the code i am trying to test:

```
return (
        <nav className='navbar'>
            { !isLoggedIn ?
                <></>
                :
                <div className="topnav">
                    <div className="allShow">
                    <h2 id="idealMeTitle">idealMe</h2>
                    <h2 className="menuIcon" onClick={()=>openMenu()}>☰</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="myLinks" style={showStyle}>
                        <NavLink to='/calories' className='nav' activeClassName='current' onClick={()=>openMenu()}>Calories</NavLink>
                        <NavLink to='/details' className='nav' activeClassName='current' onClick={()=>openMenu()}>Details</NavLink>
                        <NavLink to='/progress' className='nav' activeClassName='current' onClick={()=>openMenu()}>Progress</NavLink>
                        <NavLink to='/recipe' className='nav' activeClassName='current' onClick={()=>openMenu()}>Recipe</NavLink>
                        <button id="logoutbtn" onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </nav>
    );
}


export default NavBar;
```

and here is the test I've written:

```
test('NavLinks paths', () => {
    nav = wrapper.find('nav');
    NavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink')
    expect(wrapper.find('NavLink')).toHaveLength(4)
    let firstNavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink').first();
    let secondNavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink').second();
    let thirdNavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink').third();
    let fourthNavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink').fourth();

    expect(firstNavLink.prop('path')).toEqual('/calories');
    expect(secondNavLink.prop('path')).toEqual('/details');
    expect(thirdNavLink.prop('path')).toEqual('/progress');
    expect(fourthNavLink.prop('path')).toEqual('/recipe');
})
```

It's failing for some reason which I'm not sure about, I've looked up the documentation about React Navigation testing, but that uses memoryrouter, which i don't think is needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer:

```
test('NavLinks paths 1', () => {
    nav = wrapper.find('nav');
    NavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink')
    expect(wrapper.find('NavLink')).toHaveLength(4)
    const firstNavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink').first();
    expect(firstNavLink.prop('to')).toEqual('/calories');
})

test('NavLinks paths 2', () => {
    nav = wrapper.find('nav');
    NavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink')
    expect(wrapper.find('NavLink')).toHaveLength(4)
    const secondNavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink').at(1)
    expect(secondNavLink.prop('to')).toEqual('/details');
})

test('NavLinks paths 3', () => {
    nav = wrapper.find('nav');
    NavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink')
    expect(wrapper.find('NavLink')).toHaveLength(4)
    const thirdNavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink').at(2)
    expect(thirdNavLink.prop('to')).toEqual('/progress');
    
})

test('NavLinks paths 4', () => {
    nav = wrapper.find('nav');
    NavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink')
    expect(wrapper.find('NavLink')).toHaveLength(4)
    const fourthNavLink = wrapper.find('NavLink').at(3)
    expect(fourthNavLink.prop('to')).toEqual('/recipe');
})
```

could have been put into one test but didn't want to